# InputDialog em vertical

Tags: java, input, dialog

Meu problema é que quero criar uma interface gráfica com campos de inserção de dados na vertical, porem só consigo criar na horizontal.

*Código:*

```
JTextField mapField = new JTextField(5);
JTextField tamField = new JTextField(5);
JTextField wordField = new JTextField(5);
JTextField politicaField = new JTextField(5);
JTextField numViasField = new JTextField(5);
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Mapeamento:"));
myPanel.add(mapField);
myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); // a spacer
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Tamanho da Cache:"));
myPanel.add(tamField);
myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); // a spacer
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Wors por bloco:"));
myPanel.add(wordField);
myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); // a spacer
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Politica de substituição:"));
myPanel.add(politicaField);
myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); // a spacer
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Numero de vias:"));
myPanel.add(numViasField);
```

Comment: O StackOverflow em Português não é um fórum. Caso você tenha encontrado a resposta para sua pergunta, não edite a pergunta, apenas a responda e marque-a como aceita. Também não é necessário colocar "resolvido" no título da postagem.

Answer (score 3):

O teu problema é nao estares a usar nenhum `layout`:

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(x, y));
//x - é o numero de linhas
//y - é o numero de colunas
```

Exemplo:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GridLayoutTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayout Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 4"));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 5"));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 6"));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 7"));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 8"));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

[Fonte](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/HowtoUseGridLayout.htm)

Para te ajudar a perceber melhor os *layout*:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html